# Will an Livecode Application Developed for Ubuntu Destop work for Ubuntu Mobile?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I was wondering if the any applications developed with Livecode (www.runrev.com) for a Desktop Linux platform would be able to run natively on Ubuntu Mobile devices (tablets).

Livecode can generate Android apps and Desktop Linux apps... my question is in reference to Desktop Linux apps as I have several that I would like to use on a tablet.

If true then this would save me a great deal of re-coding Livecode for Android.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably no, because binary produced using live code is for desktop only, They do not provide option for ubuntu touch yet. Applications which run on desktop may not run on the mobile

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is old, but there are developments on the horizon which may be promising:

As the LiveCode Community Manager, I can confirm that right now there is no interface between LiveCode and Ubuntu Mobile.

However, many of us in the LiveCode community are also Ubuntu fans, and will be forming a team to explore options for using LiveCode's upcoming Themes architecture on top of the ARM Linux build LiveCode already supports to be able to deploy apps made in LiveCode to Ubuntu Mobile.

For more info on LiveCode's Themes project:
http://livecode.com/blog/2014/07/08/the-next-generation-widgets-themes/

And to see the current state of LiveCode under Linux on ARM devices, see the Raspberry Pi build at the bottom of this page:
http://downloads.livecode.com/livecode/

It'll likely be a few months until we can begin work on a Qt interface for Ubuntu Mobile, but if you'd like to lend a hand feel free to drop me an email and I'll keep you post as things move forward:  richard@livecode.org

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build for Android from LiveCode on Linux (including Ubuntu). Please see [this lesson](http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/2571/l/80751-how-do-i-become-an-android-developer-on-linux) for details.

I hope this helps.